# Convert method group to custom class that represents a function in c#

Tags: c#

I want to create a custom class that wraps a delegate and have an implicit operator to cast a method to it so I can create an invocation list, but c# doesn't allow direct cast, only 2 step cast. How can you do that?

```cs
public class Test
{
    public class CustomFunc<T> {
        private Func<T> Func { get; set; }

        public CustomFunc(Func<T> func)
        {
            Func = func;
        }

        public void DoSomething() {
        }

        public void Invoke()
        {
            //do something else
            Func.Invoke();
        }

        public static implicit operator CustomFunc<T>(Func<T> func) { return new CustomFunc<T>(func); }
    }

    public void Main() {
        AddTestMethod(TestMethod);//this gives "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Test.CustomFunc<bool>'" compilation error
        AddTestMethodThatWorks(TestMethod);//<- this works
    }

    public void AddTestMethod(CustomFunc<bool> func) {
        func.DoSomething();
        //add method to an invocation list
    }

    public void AddTestMethodThatWorks(Func<bool> func)
        => AddTestMethod(func);

    public bool TestMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett it doesn't matter how related they are. That's what an implicit operator does. It makes them related and gives you the option to cast from one to another.

Comment: I'm confident he knows what implicit operators are and what they do, and that he only missed that you had an implicit operator in your question.

Comment: @DanielTranca I had missed the implicit operator. Your problem is that `TestMethod` isn't `Func<bool>`; it's a method group that *can be cast* to `Func<bool>`. `AddTestMethod((Func<bool>)TestMethod)` will invoke your implicit cast operator. The reasoning behind this is that there may be multiple overloads of TestMethod with different prototypes, and the compiler will not get involved in picking a best match, even when there only *is* one match, and it's a perfect match. So my first remarks had a grain of sense after all: A method group is really different.

Comment: @Amy Thanks, but it serves me right for commenting before closely reading the question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you can cast also to ````AddTestMethod((CustomFunc<bool>)TestMethod);````. But the idea to have an implicit operator would be to remove the said cast, right? And also, the idea is that if you call AddTestMethodThatWorks which calls AddTestMethod, there is no casting, meaning the implicit operator works fine.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have to call the Add method a lot of times and in my case I have to put 2 params of CustomFunc type and I don't want to have to specify the cast every time.

Comment: @DanielTranca I would certainly want to make this work the way you're trying to do it.

Comment: AddTestMethodThatWorks has an implicit cast of your method group to `Func<bool>`, which works. `Func<bool> x = TestMethod;` would work too. Then it has a implicit cast of `Func<bool>` (*already cast*) to `CustomFunc<bool>`. The compiler will take one step on its own, not two.

Comment: You've asked a "why not?" question, but "why not?" questions are vague. Are you asking "what line of the C# specification describes how user-defined implicit conversions are analyzed?"  Are you asking "what were the design factors discussed in the meeting in 2001 that came up with the rules for implicit conversions?"  What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @EdPlunkett exactly my point. The reason I asked is because I thought someone would know how to cast directly to the item that I need (method group) rather than the intermediate. I would like to have the option to create an implicit operator like this ````public static implicit operator CustomFunc<T>([method group] func)````.

Comment: @DanielTranca: If that's your question then I suggest that you edit the question to ask that question, rather than asking "why is the language not the way I want it to be?" The answer to the question "how do I do an implicit no-cast conversion from a method group to an arbitrary type in C#?" is "you don't; the language was not designed to allow that".

Comment: @EdPlunkett does that mean that my approach is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: @DanielTranca Personally, because I'm dumb and lazy, and the subject is complicated and poorly understood, I'd abandon all thoughts of the implicit cast. How many overloads of AddTestMethod do you have, for different values of `T`?

Comment: Since I'm planning to use this as a plugin in multiple projects it'll be called for a lot of possible values of T and a lot of times.

Comment: `AddTestMethod<T>(CustomFunc<T> func)`, `AddTestMethodThatWorks<T>(Func<T> func) => AddTestMethod<T>(new CustomFunc<T>(func));` look good from here -- however: Does `//add method to an invocation list` refer to the same invocation list (literally, the same collection class instance) for different values of `T`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question (as originally stated, before recent edits) is somewhat vague. Let's start by formulating a crisp question:

> Is there a way in C# to convert directly, without a cast, via a user-defined implicit conversion, from a method group to an arbitrary type?

No.

Well that was an easy answer to write, but possibly unsatisfying.  Let's ask another crisp question:

> Where are the rules for user-defined implicit conversions described?

Ostensibly here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#processing-of-user-defined-implicit-conversions

A careful reading of that section immediately shows why we have a problem:

> A user-defined implicit conversion from type S to type T is processed as follows:

Method groups do not have a type, and so any rule that begins "conversion from type" is likely to not apply to method groups. However, that's not the real problem here. The real problem lies in the rules for determining the semantics of user-defined implicit conversions.

> Can you briefly summarize the rules for implicit user-defined conversions?

Briefly, the rule is that the "source" expressions may have a "standard" conversion -- that is, not a user-defined conversion -- put "on top" of it before the user-defined conversion. For example, if we have a user defined conversion from `double` to `Square`, and we are converting an `int` to `Square?`, then the `int` is allowed to first be converted to `double` via a "standard" conversion, and then to `Square`, and then to `Square?`.  You can end up chaining several "standard" conversions if you are clever, but you never end up chaining two user-defined conversions.

Unfortunately for you, method group conversions are not considered "standard implicit conversions".

> What are the standard implicit conversions?

Identity, numeric, reference, boxing, nullable, and generic type parameter conversions are standard conversions. Conversions involving method groups, lambdas and anonymous functions are not standard conversions, and obviously user-defined conversions are not standard conversions.

> What were the design considerations made in favour of restricting method group conversions from the standard conversions?

We considered method group conversions to be potentially confusing when used in user-defined conversions because (1) they may involve overload resolution (2) they may involve various kinds of inference, and (3) we did not consider scenarios such as yours to be likely in line-of-business scenarios.  Basically, they would complicate a feature that is already too complicated and poorly understood, for very little gain. We had other things to spend effort on.

If you have a business scenario that would strongly motivate re-examining this design decision, consider raising an issue on the github site and start a new discussion.  Things may have changed since 2001 when the decision was made to not allow method group conversions as a standard conversion.

---

If you're reading this answer carefully you'll have noted that I said "ostensibly" above.

> Why did you do that, Eric?

First, because the spec was supposed to be rewritten to include rules for "conversion from expression" instead of "conversion from type", but apparently this has not happened yet in the online version of the spec. I wrote the notes for that in 2012; I am vexed that it has not made it into the online spec yet.

Second, because the compiler does not exactly implement the rules in the specification.

> What are the actual rules for user-defined implicit conversions?

Great question. I wrote extensive notes on that subject, here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Semantics/Conversions/UserDefinedImplicitConversions.cs

If you wish to understand how exactly user-defined implicit conversion operators really work in C#, you'll have to read all those comments. I know, they are very long.  You will find that they take you less time to read than they took me to write.

If none of the above answers your question, please ask a less vague question; I am happy to answer crisp questions about this feature area, which is complicated and poorly understood.

Comment: I still stand by my question which is in the title and the first phrase of the post. I do agree that I could have been a bit more specific, but what I wanted to do is to cast a method group to a specific custom class using an implicit operator. The why was there for the fact that it didn't work, a question which Ed answered for me, but yeah, your answer does make sense and, indeed, it answers my question. Couldn't care for the tone though.

Comment: All I wanted was to bypass the second cast by using another implicit operator or some other trick. Nevertheless, considering all of the above, is the solution I have above the best one to bypass this without specifying the cast every time I have to call the method?

Comment: @DanielTranca: Glad to help. The tone is clear and straightforward; if you have a criticism on the merits of the answer rather than your interpretation of tone, I'd be happy to consider it.

Comment: @DanielTranca: I have no basis upon which to judge what you'd consider "best".  Can you describe for me some of the metrics for "betterness" that you'd consider?

Comment: let's say reusability, efficiency and visibility.

Comment: @DanielTranca Please say "efficiency" when you mean "I have concerns, based on the following measurements, about runtime performance", not when you mean "I don't like typing". The latter gives me brain cancer, so I hope that's not what you meant.

Comment: @DanielTranca: And now we see the problem, because some of those metrics contradict each other, and then require judgment as to the relative merits. Consider for example the design of conversion logic in Visual Basic.  VB is much more lenient than C# in allowing the sorts of conversions you want, though I am not enough of a VB expert to say whether your scenario would work out of the box in that language. But point being: VB will do things like, if it detects that there's a delegate conversion ...

Comment: ... that the CLR does not allow as a (possibly variant) reference conversion, it will *allocate a new delegate of the desired type that calls the old one*. That is super readable from the developer's perspective, and the compiler makes a program that does what you want -- except when it doesn't.  It is surprising that a delegate conversion can allocate an extra object, it is surprising that it loses referential identity, and it is surprising that it introduces an indirection penalty on the call.  So those work against efficiency.

Comment: My point is: as you've discovered, there are techniques you can use that may involve extra indirections and extra allocations, but those work against efficiency. They may also cause surprises; one reasonably expects that delegate conversions preserve identity, but your new kind of conversion does not, the same as VB. So what then is the "best" course to chart given these contradictions? That's the essence of design, and you'll have to consult with your stakeholders to work out what the right balance is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It took me distressingly long reading your last comment, to realize that by "typing" you meant the act of making keystrokes, and not the act of making type annotations manifest in a program. :)